# Why cant I get mv to rename and copy file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The last thing I want to do in this script is take the `userinput` to rename the corresponding files to include `.bak` extension rather then `.txt` which will copy into a `backup` directory. I keep receiving an error messaging saying e.g.

```
mv: cannot stat '5.bak': No such file or directory
```

The snippet in question (right at the bottom of full code):

```
for i in ~/students/Stu$userinput/*_$userinput.txt;
do
        mkdir -p ~/students/Backup; mv -- "$i" "${userinput%.txt}.bak" ~/students/Backup; #Change extension.

done
```

Full code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Current User:  $USER"  >> system_info.txt #Inputs current user in .txt file.
echo "Current Directory:  $PWD"  >> system_info.txt #Inputs current user directory in .txt file.

#Creating the directory structure in the users home directory.
for i in {1..20}; #Create sub-directory of Stu from 1 to 20.
do
        mkdir -p archive students/Stu${i}; #Two new dirctories created, with Stu having sub directories represented by {i},
done


i=1 #{i} to begin at 1.
until ((i>20)) #Each loop to check if i is greater than 20.
do
        touch ~/students/Stu${i}/Notes_$i.txt #Creates a Notes page for every i up to 20.
        touch ~/students/Stu${i}/Results_$i.txt #Similarily, creates a txt file for Results_$ up untill 20.
        ((i++))
done

for i in {1..20}; do #This is to echo the required sentence howcasing the current filename, user in the corresponding directory.
        filename=~/students/Stu${i}/Notes_$i.txt
        touch "$filename"
        echo "The $(basename -- "$filename") file belonging to $USER was created in the Stu${i}." >> ~/students/Stu${i}/Notes_$i.txt
done

for i in {1..20}; do #This is to echo the required sentence howcasing the current filename, user in the corresponding directory.
        filename=~/students/Stu${i}/Notes_$i.txt
        touch "$filename"
        echo "The $(basename -- "$filename") file belonging to $USER was created in the Stu${i}." >> ~/students/Stu${i}/Notes_$i.txt
done

for i in {1..20}; do
        file_name=~/students/Stu${i}/Results_$i.txt
        touch "$file_name"
        echo "The $(basename -- "$file_name") file belonging to $USER was created in the Stu${i}." >> ~/students/Stu${i}/Results_$i.txt
done

while true;
do
        echo -n "File to change: "
        read userinput #Sets variable

if [ "$userinput" -ge 1 ] && [ "$userinput" -le 20 ];then #If userinput is greater than or equal to 1 or lss than or equal to 20/
        echo "Valid number! File changed." #If fits crities, let user kniw
break
else #If critriea doesnt meet, try again.
        echo "Invalid! File number must be between 1-20. Please try again."
        fi
done

for i in ~/students/Stu$userinput/*_$userinput.txt;
do
        mkdir -p ~/students/Backup; mv -- "$i" "${userinput%.txt}.bak" ~/students/Backup; #Change extension.

done


echo $?
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct one would be

```
cp $i ~/students/Backup/$(basename ${i%.txt}.bak);
```

Note: `mkdir -p ~/students/Backup` is not needed to put in the loop

Comment: `"mv: cannot stat '5.bak': No such file or directory"` -- replace `"mv"` with `"cp"` and the same result will occur -- only this time the error will read `"cp: cannot stat '5.bak': No such file or directory"`

Comment: yeah, i had tried with cp and was unable to get it working.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think no. The original one takes multiple sources and move to the destination `~/students/Backup`. `"${userinput%.txt}.bak"` is also a source

Comment: @BicSwan Have you tried exactly my command ??

Comment: If the issue is `"No such file or directory"` it doesn't matter whether your try and `mv` the file or `cp` it -- there is still `No such file or directory"`. What the error is saying this the loop variable `i` contains `5.txt`. After the *parameter expansion* the `txt` is replaced with `bak` creating `5.bak`. The `mv` command has the form `mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY` and the file `5.bak` cannot be found.

Comment: `mv a b dir` does not actually rename a to b then move to `dir`. It does move a and b directly to `dir`. In this case b does not exist

Comment: @nhatnq Your code does work but it doesn't do exactly what I need it do. It only takes `Results_{userinuput}.txt` and rename its it to `{userinput}.bak`. I would need it to take both existing `.txt` in the corresponding directory e.g. User inputs 2, script changes `Notes_2.txt` and `Results_2.txt` in the `Stu2` directory, renames extension to `Notes_2.bak` `Results_2.bak` and copies new versions over to new `~students/Backup` directory.

Comment: @nhatnq Just tried it out and returning error `cp: cannot create regular file '/home/local/USERS/pbssoker/students/Backup//home/local/USERS/pbssoker/students/Stu3/Notes_3.bak': No such file or directory` do you think it could be something with what @DavidC.Rankin was referring to?

Comment: @BicSwan check latest one, it should work

Comment: @nhatnq Absolute legend!! thank you so much!! It’s been driving me crazy for over a week!!